# How to stop autoplay immediately when hover in Swiper

Tags: swiper.js

I made custom feature to stop auto play when user hover on swiper. It is working but there is a problem. It won't stop immediately, instead of it has delay time = swiper's speed. How to stop it immediately. Please help me.

```
swiper.hover( function() {
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
}, function() {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
} );
```

Comment: i've tried to implement the code above but the hover doens't affect the autoplay on my end. Do you have `disableOnInteraction` set to `true`?